# Is the order of file-level static variables always the same within a given translation unit?

Tags: c++, initialization, static-initialization, static-order-fiasco

I have a program split up into two source files:

*example.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
   A(int x) {
      ::std::cout << "In A(" << x << ")\n";
   }
};

static A first(1);
static A second(2);
```

*example*__*main.cpp*

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   return 0;
}
```

Is the output of this program guaranteed to be:

```
In A(1)
In A(2)
```

on all platforms and compilers? If so, where in the standard does it say this? Does it matter if I'm using namespaces and `first` and `second` appear in different namespaces? How about if they aren't static and I'm using an anonymous namespace?

Comment: Short answer is yes, usual caution is "don't rely on it since you may want to refactor this into two different files", usual cure is lazy initialized singletons/pimpl'ed objects and I will let language lawyers quote the relevent verse from the Book.

Comment: @AlexandreC. - In this particular case some macros (**bleah** I know) are used to make them stick together. Refactoring in the manner you described will not occur, or at least it won't surprise anybody if it doesn't work when the macros involved are separated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order of initialization is defined for non-local static objects if the declarations appear in the same translation unit.

From C++03,

> (3.6/2) Objects with static storage duration defined in namespace scope in the
>   same translation unit and dynamically initialized shall be initialized
>   in the order in which their definition appears in the translation
>   unit.  [Note: 8.5.1 describes the order in which aggregate members are
>   initialized.  The initial-ization of local static objects is described
>   in 6.7.  ]

Answer (score 3):

Within one translation unit, global variables are initialized in several stages:

- First, all variables that have "static initialization" are initialized in their order of declaration (see below).
- Then, all "ordered dynamic initializations" are performed, again in their order of declaration.
- There are also "unordered dynamic initializations", which are "unsequenced" with respect to the other dynamic initializations (but always after the static ones).

Destruction of statically and ordered-dynamically initialized globals proceeds in opposite order (and the unordered ones again "unsequenced", but before the static ones). The relative initialization ordering across TUs is unspecified.

To explain the terminology loosely: a global variable is "statically initialized" if it is either initialized to a constant (for constructor calls, this requires `constexpr` constructors), or if it is has no initializer and is declared `static` (which makes it zero-initialized): `static int a; Foo b(1, true, Blue);` On the other hand, if the initializer is not anything "constant", like a function call or a non-constexpr constructor, then the object is "dynamically initialized". Most ordinary globals that are dynamically initialized are "ordered"; the only "unordered" ones are static members of template specializations and such like.

(Note that all this got a lot more detailed in C++11, as there is now explicit attention to thread-local storage and initialization at the start of a thread.)

Comment: Actually that's not completely true... first are performed all the static initializations, then all the dynamic ones.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: What do you mean by "dynamic ones"?

Comment: "Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any dynamic initialization takes place." [basic.start.init] ¶2

Comment: As far as I can tell, zero-initialization is performed for every non-local variable before other initialization takes place; then happens static initialization (where objects are initialized *from constants*); then dynamic initialization, where objects are initialized - I suppose - from other objects.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Oh OK, let me update that -- what about extern constants, though?

Comment: On the other hand, thinking again about it, these last objects must be defined *after* the static-initialized ones (otherwise you could not use them as parameters of the constructor/initialization expression), so your statement should be correct - and is actually backed up by the sentence "Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their definitions in the translation unit.".

Comment: Do extern constants even exist? :S

Comment: @MatteoItalia: yes, sure -- it's just a normal, global variable that's constant. But constant globals are by default `static`, so you have to override with `extern`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - I believe they do. :-)